# Memory leak prevention - is it necessary here?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently writing a program in Java and it's been a long time since I've done any programming, and even longer since I've done any dynamic memory allocation, and longer yet since I've programmed in Java!

Can you please tell me: should I delete/free/etc dataBytes array, or should I leave it for garbage collection, or will it automatically delete/free the memory when it exits the myFunc() scope?

P.S. I realize that if myFunc isn't called frequently, memory will likely never be an issue but please humor me, as I know I will be using dynamic memory allocation much more in the future as my app gets closer to launch.

```
public void myFunc() {
    byte[] dataBytes = null;

    try {
        // Open data file and read contents to byte array buffer
        InputStream inputFile= parent.getAssets().open("myFile.txt");

        dataBytes = new byte[inputFile.available()];

        taxesFile.read(dataBytes);
        taxesFile.close();

        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to open myFile.txt");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no `delete`/`free` in Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you do not need to manually free/delete memory. The garbage collector will take care.

Also, whenever you create a new object, it is created on the heap. Again, you will never need to free any memory, even the heap memory.

Answer (score 1):

Java's GC considers objects "garbage" if they aren't reachable through a chain starting at a GC root.

There are four kinds of GC roots in Java:

1. Local variables are kept alive by the stack of a thread. This is not a real object virtual reference and thus is not visible. For all intents and purposes, local variables are GC roots.
2. Active Java threads are always considered live objects and are therefore GC roots. This is especially important for thread local variables.
3. Static variables are referenced by their classes. This fact makes them de facto GC roots. Classes themselves can be garbage-collected, which would remove all referenced static variables. This is of special importance when we use application servers, OSGi containers or class loaders in general.
4. JNI References are Java objects that the native code has created as part of a JNI call. Objects thus created are treated specially because the JVM does not know if it is being referenced by the native code or not. Such objects represent a very special form of GC root.

> should I delete/free/etc dataBytes array, or should I leave it for garbage collection, or will it automatically delete/free the memory when it exits the myFunc() scope

Even if you set the `dataBytes` array reference to `null` or request a GC with `System.gc()` it is not guaranteed . Once the method returns and its stack is clear then the local variable holding reference to that array object will be purged . If that array object is not referenced by any other active reference variable , it will be eligible for garbage collection. Let the JVM take care.